# Can we use plugins like Helmet.js and body-parser to secure a serverless function? If not, any alternatives?

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Can we use plugins like Helmet.js and body-parser to secure a serverless function? If we can't how can we implement those features to our serverless functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In AWS, you can setup a distributed architecture using other services to filter requests before hitting your serverless functions. You can use [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) to protect your API Gateway Endpoints (Currently you have to proxy your API through CloudFront).

Check the following diagram and refer the [AWS documentation](https://d0.awsstatic.com/aws-answers/answers-images/waf-solution-architecture.png) for more details.

[image]
Diagram Credits: AWS answers for AWS WAF Security Automations

Comment: Thanks Ashan. A firewall is a great option. But, what are the things we can do inside the function to protect it?

Comment: When having separate WAF you can focus on writing business logic in your functions by delegating the responsibility of handling vulnerable request by WAF. Also you can use a separate Lamda to write custom protection logic and plug into WAF.

Inside the function you can do validations and data filtering based on your authorization model (Even authentication handles outside these function). In addition also a part of the validation can be done in API Gateway using mapping templates.